# Google Chrome displays some gray jpgs with pink overlay

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, browser, colors, jpeg

The problem appears on site http://ui-cloud.com/ and a lot of other.
[image: For example: ui-cloud.com]

If I save the image from the site and open it in some image viewer app, then image displays correct. Also all other browsers in the system display this image correctly.

What causes the problem?

My system info:

1. Windows 8 x64
2. Google Chrome Version 22.0.1229.96 m
3. nVidia GTX 460M with 306.97 drivers.

Comment: Windows 8 x64, Chrome 24.0.1312.5 dev-m, nVidia Quadro 600: not having that problem...

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux do you have some Adobe products installed?

Comment: I have Photoshop CS6 and After Effects CS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have fixed the issue. All I needed is to remove profile associated with my display device.
[image]

Comment: Interesting. The Google Chrome release log says it started support for ICC profiles in Sept 2012.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the background image uses a non-standard palette. In your URL, the image is http://ui-cloud.com/wp-content/themes/uicloud/images/body-bg.jpg. If you save that, and view its properties, it was created with Adobe Illustrator CS5. That's a hint that when it was saved, it used the default Adobe RGB palette instead of a web safe standard RGB palette (sRGB).
Unfortunately, browsers will display non-standard palettes differently. IE and FireFox seem to display this image the same as it appears in an image editor, Chrome does not.  Using chrome's optional color management switch (--enable-monitor-profile on the chrome start command line) did not help with this problem.

If you have control over the content, there are several threads about using converters to fix the palette incompatibilities, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817727/converting-jpeg-colorspace-adobe-rgb-to-srgb-on-linux). I used an image editor that converted the palette, and that fixed the Chrome display discrepancy.

But where you aren't able to control the content, I wasn't able to find any easy solution on the google chrome help page. Perhaps someone else will know how to modify how Chrome renders these adobe palettes more consistently.

Comment: Seemes to be only on my PC. May be some adobe products installed on my pc causes such palette problem?